# Strace command in Linux for tracing DMA transfers

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, system-calls, dma, strace

Is there a way to trace system calls related to DMA transfers with `strace` command in Linux. I use the Zedboard which consist of FPGA and ARM A9 Core. I use the Linardo version of Linux (Linaro 12.11) where tool support is not available for using `perf` command (No package error- when installing). Please share any alternative commands that can help in tracing system calls related to DMA transfers. In my case, I have an application running on Linux where it transfer data with FPGA via DMA (which is the part of interest).

Comment: The short answer is:  not with strace.  But, there is [always] a way. I've been writing linux drivers for 20+ and I'm very good at R/T tracing, performance, etc. Please edit your post to provide more info about tool chain, system architecture--the more the better. The "way" will dictated by the environment. Do you want all DMA [or just specific devs]? What ways in/out do you have to get the trace data (e.g. ethernet or other hispeed link, bus to host CPU, etc.)  Using an FPGA? What CPU? What is your comfort level with kernel hacking [if needed]? kernel version and kconfig? DRAM size?

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for your comment. I have updated the post. In my case I use Linardo which is a Linux distribution for ARM cores. The end target is Zedboard which consist of ARM A9 and FPGA. The application initiates transfers between the Core and FPGA. The part of interest is to sniff the back end system calls. The uname -a command gives 
 Linux zed2 3.15.0-xilinx+ #16 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 12 22:24:14 SGT 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: DMA transfers?!  Do you just want to trace syscalls of app at syscall boundary to kernel [I'm not sure what you mean by "the back end"] or do you need to go deeper [deep driver tracing]?  Anyway, trace data has to "go somewhere".  For strace, normally to disk.  Herein, no disk [AFAICT].  So, zedboard has GigE port, yes?  I'd connect the port to a host PC and do something like [not exact syntax] `strace ... | socket_blaster`.  "socket_blaster" could be `ncat` [with another ncat on host].  What is the IDE?  If no ncat, can you build from source and add it?  Or, any other useful trace app?

Comment: To be more specific, a part of the application (you can consider this to be a C code) does some DMA transfers. The transfers are taking long in an OS environment and the idea is to debug this. In the initial round of studies it was proven that this is not happening due to pre emptions. Now one suspect is the Virtual -Physical memory conversion. The goal is to trace the system calls and analyse this. There are no IDEs used and the hardware is controlled remotely. The access is only via terminal.

Comment: How do you know it does DMA transfers? Any specific IP you are talking about? Driver level? Or what?

Comment: The application is a C code which is modifiable. An IP is there in the FPGA. The IP vendor provides APIs to transfer data between DDR and the FPGA. With these APIs, transfers can be initiated.